# how to now in as3 file details like date created with url without browse or select a file

Tags: actionscript-3, file, browser, flash-cs5, flash-cc

how to now in as3 file details like date created with url  without browse or select a file

i want know mFileReference.creationDate without browse() or select a file

but i want  creationDate  to file without user know this

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to read but I think you want to know the creationDate of a file on the user's computer without the user having to select it?

That's **not possible** with Flash in the browser, because you don't have free access to the file system of the user's machine. It would be a very big security hole if you could access user's files without their permission.